# Trouble sending message to RichEdit control with winapi c#

Tags: c#, winapi, user32, richedit

Im currently working on a solution for an automation of unmanaged, external code, so im having some trouble setting the text to a RichEdit control.

I have tried sending a WM_SETTEXT but it only sets the first letter of the string to the control.

Other things i have tried: PostMessage, EM_SETTEXTEX, SetWindowText, and i have unsuccessfully tried EM_STREAMIN, but there isn't a simple enough example of that message.

The specific class of the richEdit is:
WindowsForms10.RichEdit20W.app.0.141b42a_r14_ad1

My code:

```
IntPtr Text;
string bar;

...

//Function call
setRichEditText(Text, bar);

...

//Function declaration
private static int setRichEditText(IntPtr hWnd, string text) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
    int result = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, (IntPtr)sb.Length, sb.ToString());
    return result;
}

...

//Imported function
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lParam);
```

Is There a way to make it set the whole string or maybe a workaround?

Comment: Smells like you passing UTF 16 but the control interprets it as ANSI

Comment: But wouldn't it just be easier to use UI Automation

Comment: `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]` - That's a bug.

Comment: Im using UIAVerify, winSpy, spy++, and AutomationSpy. I cant hold to just one tool because one tool just doesnt provides me everything i need.

Comment: No one was suggesting to use a tool. [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) is a programming interface.

Answer (score 0):

finally solved it!

Worked with:

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, sb.ToString());
```